# Unable to View Slider

Tags: php, html

I am working on an image slider for a website using PHP, but the `div` class has `data-src` and the slider is not loading. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is what I have already done:

```
<div id="camera" class="camera-wrap">
    <div data-src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/index_slide01.jpg">
        <div class="fadeIn camera_caption">
            <h2 class="text_1 color_1">Solutions that you need!</h2>
            <a class="btn_1" href="#">More info</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might do the trick for you

```
<div data-src="<?php echo base_url();?>/images/index_slide01.jpg">
```

Just added `/` infront of `images`

becuase `echo base_url();` will return `http://example.com/website` and not the `/` at the end of it. So to make a complete path you need to add `/` slash infront of Images folder.